# Placeholder in Contactform 7 - Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am making a website for a client of me but im running into a problem.
I've made a contact form in wordpress using Contact Form 7. This plugin is really easy to use but when i wanted to use the placeholder property of the plugin it did not show the placeholder when i loaded the page.

This is how i set the placeholder in Contactform 7

```
[text* your-name placeholder "Name"]
```

The placeholder tag works just fine for my textarea but it doesnt work with the textbox above.
Can someone explain to me what i am doeing wrong here?

**EDIT**

When i inspect the element with Google Chrome and inspect the textbox it says that it has a placeholder. But it doesnt show the placeholder.

Comment: `[text* first-name placeholder "Name"]` works fine in one of my forms.  What browser are you using?  If you view your page source, does the HTML input have a `placeholder` attribute?  Mine generates `<input type="text" name="first-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name" />`, for example.

Comment: [text* text-291 placeholder "Your Hobbies"]  worked perfect for me in my localhost

Comment: @Hobo i am using Google Chrome, but i also tested it in firefox

Comment: Ok, so it's not a compatibility thing.  So does the `placeholder` attribute appear in the page source (`Ctrl-U` in Chrome) as it does for me (see above)?

Comment: What color is the placeholder text?

Comment: Same problem but none of the answers work. First time seeing something like this, I'll post an answer if I find a solution

Answer (score 18):

If anyone is having trouble with this, it could be that you're using class: or id: attributes.

It worked for me when I added placeholder **after** all those:

```
[email* your-email id:your-email class:form-control placeholder "ex. Jon.Smith@email.com"]
```

Comment: This is the important information **always put placeholder at the end**

Comment: This is the correct solution. As @MaxiGui stated, the placeholder must go LAST, even though the CF7 documentation does not mention that.

Answer (score 4):

Its very simple.You can add placeholder like this:

```
[text* first_name placeholder"First Name"]
```

Documentation : https://contactform7.com/setting-placeholder-text/

Answer (score 2):

Same problem, then I change the input background color and the placeholder text is white on background white ...

So I sudgest to try to change the backrgound input color to test:

```
input[type="text"], textarea {
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[text* your-name placeholder "Name"] The syntax was what you gave correct once check the contact form settings. Because I am also using same as like your syntax it was working properly in my contact form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class or id attributes.Simply do the following:

```
[text* your-name class:form-control id:name placeholder "Enter Name"]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please elaborate and format your answer and explain how it is different from the existing answers?

Comment: Write the placeholder last in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still having this problem despite having everything correctly written as the other answers above, here is the solution to my problem.

Code in a theme was hiding placeholders and it's not related to Contact Form 7.

CSS Code that fixed my problem:

```
input::placeholder {
    color: #9c9c9c;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a placeholder like this.

```
[text* full-name placeholder "Full Name"]
```

if the placeholder doesn't show again please give style for placeholder like below:

```
form input::placeholder{color: #9C9898; font-size: 14px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add placeholder like this:
[text* your-name placeholder="Enter Name"]