# Sup digit in Contact Form 7 placeholder?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to show a number superscript like `<sup> 2 <sup>` in a Contact Form 7 placeholder. But I have just discovered that you can apparently use no HTML tags in the CF7 elements. I planned it like this:

`[text your-size placeholder "area in m <sup> 2 </ sup> approx."]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder in Contactform 7 - Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309750/placeholder-in-contactform-7-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

Contact form 7 doesn't allow HTML in the placeholder. So, we can do that with the `jQuery` and `Unicode`. Add the below code in your js file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $( '#FormID #area' ).attr( 'placeholder', "area in m\u00B2 approx.");
    // here #FormID is the ID of form and #area is id of your text field.

});
```